# getting a windows message name

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a windows program that I'm extending with a DLL.  I include debug code through a debug stream objects that print through OutputDebugString and I can view with DebugView.  Part of the interface is a message processing function.

```
__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT messageProc(UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  dbg << "Message received " << Message  << endl;
  return TRUE;
```

My question is if there is a function to retrieve the name of an message from the code.  For example instead of the output "message received 534"  I would like to see "message received WM_MOVING"  to more appropriately distinguish and filter the debug output.

Answer (score 14):

C++ 11

From [List Of Window Messages](https://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages)
thx to @arx for the link.

**Usage:**

```
#include <map>

int messagenumber = 5;
const char* translatedMessage = wmTranslation[messagenumber];
if (translatedMessage == NULL)
{
    translatedMessage = "UnknownMessage";
}
```

**Translation-Data:**

```
static std::map<int, const char*> wmTranslation = {
{0, "WM_NULL" },
{1, "WM_CREATE" },
{2, "WM_DESTROY" },
{3, "WM_MOVE" },
{5, "WM_SIZE" },
{6, "WM_ACTIVATE" },
{7, "WM_SETFOCUS" },
{8, "WM_KILLFOCUS" },
{10, "WM_ENABLE" },
{11, "WM_SETREDRAW" },
{12, "WM_SETTEXT" },
{13, "WM_GETTEXT" },
{14, "WM_GETTEXTLENGTH" },
{15, "WM_PAINT" },
{16, "WM_CLOSE" },
{17, "WM_QUERYENDSESSION" },
{18, "WM_QUIT" },
{19, "WM_QUERYOPEN" },
{20, "WM_ERASEBKGND" },
{21, "WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE" },
{22, "WM_ENDSESSION" },
{24, "WM_SHOWWINDOW" },
{25, "WM_CTLCOLOR" },
{26, "WM_WININICHANGE" },
{27, "WM_DEVMODECHANGE" },
{28, "WM_ACTIVATEAPP" },
{29, "WM_FONTCHANGE" },
{30, "WM_TIMECHANGE" },
{31, "WM_CANCELMODE" },
{32, "WM_SETCURSOR" },
{33, "WM_MOUSEACTIVATE" },
{34, "WM_CHILDACTIVATE" },
{35, "WM_QUEUESYNC" },
{36, "WM_GETMINMAXINFO" },
{38, "WM_PAINTICON" },
{39, "WM_ICONERASEBKGND" },
{40, "WM_NEXTDLGCTL" },
{42, "WM_SPOOLERSTATUS" },
{43, "WM_DRAWITEM" },
{44, "WM_MEASUREITEM" },
{45, "WM_DELETEITEM" },
{46, "WM_VKEYTOITEM" },
{47, "WM_CHARTOITEM" },
{48, "WM_SETFONT" },
{49, "WM_GETFONT" },
{50, "WM_SETHOTKEY" },
{51, "WM_GETHOTKEY" },
{55, "WM_QUERYDRAGICON" },
{57, "WM_COMPAREITEM" },
{61, "WM_GETOBJECT" },
{65, "WM_COMPACTING" },
{68, "WM_COMMNOTIFY" },
{70, "WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING" },
{71, "WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED" },
{72, "WM_POWER" },
{73, "WM_COPYGLOBALDATA" },
{74, "WM_COPYDATA" },
{75, "WM_CANCELJOURNAL" },
{78, "WM_NOTIFY" },
{80, "WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST" },
{81, "WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE" },
{82, "WM_TCARD" },
{83, "WM_HELP" },
{84, "WM_USERCHANGED" },
{85, "WM_NOTIFYFORMAT" },
{123, "WM_CONTEXTMENU" },
{124, "WM_STYLECHANGING" },
{125, "WM_STYLECHANGED" },
{126, "WM_DISPLAYCHANGE" },
{127, "WM_GETICON" },
{128, "WM_SETICON" },
{129, "WM_NCCREATE" },
{130, "WM_NCDESTROY" },
{131, "WM_NCCALCSIZE" },
{132, "WM_NCHITTEST" },
{133, "WM_NCPAINT" },
{134, "WM_NCACTIVATE" },
{135, "WM_GETDLGCODE" },
{136, "WM_SYNCPAINT" },
{160, "WM_NCMOUSEMOVE" },
{161, "WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN" },
{162, "WM_NCLBUTTONUP" },
{163, "WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK" },
{164, "WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN" },
{165, "WM_NCRBUTTONUP" },
{166, "WM_NCRBUTTONDBLCLK" },
{167, "WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN" },
{168, "WM_NCMBUTTONUP" },
{169, "WM_NCMBUTTONDBLCLK" },
{171, "WM_NCXBUTTONDOWN" },
{172, "WM_NCXBUTTONUP" },
{173, "WM_NCXBUTTONDBLCLK" },
{176, "EM_GETSEL" },
{177, "EM_SETSEL" },
{178, "EM_GETRECT" },
{179, "EM_SETRECT" },
{180, "EM_SETRECTNP" },
{181, "EM_SCROLL" },
{182, "EM_LINESCROLL" },
{183, "EM_SCROLLCARET" },
{185, "EM_GETMODIFY" },
{187, "EM_SETMODIFY" },
{188, "EM_GETLINECOUNT" },
{189, "EM_LINEINDEX" },
{190, "EM_SETHANDLE" },
{191, "EM_GETHANDLE" },
{192, "EM_GETTHUMB" },
{193, "EM_LINELENGTH" },
{194, "EM_REPLACESEL" },
{195, "EM_SETFONT" },
{196, "EM_GETLINE" },
{197, "EM_LIMITTEXT" },
{197, "EM_SETLIMITTEXT" },
{198, "EM_CANUNDO" },
{199, "EM_UNDO" },
{200, "EM_FMTLINES" },
{201, "EM_LINEFROMCHAR" },
{202, "EM_SETWORDBREAK" },
{203, "EM_SETTABSTOPS" },
{204, "EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR" },
{205, "EM_EMPTYUNDOBUFFER" },
{206, "EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE" },
{207, "EM_SETREADONLY" },
{209, "EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC" },
{209, "EM_GETWORDBREAKPROC" },
{210, "EM_GETPASSWORDCHAR" },
{211, "EM_SETMARGINS" },
{212, "EM_GETMARGINS" },
{213, "EM_GETLIMITTEXT" },
{214, "EM_POSFROMCHAR" },
{215, "EM_CHARFROMPOS" },
{216, "EM_SETIMESTATUS" },
{217, "EM_GETIMESTATUS" },
{224, "SBM_SETPOS" },
{225, "SBM_GETPOS" },
{226, "SBM_SETRANGE" },
{227, "SBM_GETRANGE" },
{228, "SBM_ENABLE_ARROWS" },
{230, "SBM_SETRANGEREDRAW" },
{233, "SBM_SETSCROLLINFO" },
{234, "SBM_GETSCROLLINFO" },
{235, "SBM_GETSCROLLBARINFO" },
{240, "BM_GETCHECK" },
{241, "BM_SETCHECK" },
{242, "BM_GETSTATE" },
{243, "BM_SETSTATE" },
{244, "BM_SETSTYLE" },
{245, "BM_CLICK" },
{246, "BM_GETIMAGE" },
{247, "BM_SETIMAGE" },
{248, "BM_SETDONTCLICK" },
{255, "WM_INPUT" },
{256, "WM_KEYDOWN" },
{256, "WM_KEYFIRST" },
{257, "WM_KEYUP" },
{258, "WM_CHAR" },
{259, "WM_DEADCHAR" },
{260, "WM_SYSKEYDOWN" },
{261, "WM_SYSKEYUP" },
{262, "WM_SYSCHAR" },
{263, "WM_SYSDEADCHAR" },
{264, "WM_KEYLAST" },
{265, "WM_UNICHAR" },
{265, "WM_WNT_CONVERTREQUESTEX" },
{266, "WM_CONVERTREQUEST" },
{267, "WM_CONVERTRESULT" },
{268, "WM_INTERIM" },
{269, "WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION" },
{270, "WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION" },
{271, "WM_IME_COMPOSITION" },
{271, "WM_IME_KEYLAST" },
{272, "WM_INITDIALOG" },
{273, "WM_COMMAND" },
{274, "WM_SYSCOMMAND" },
{275, "WM_TIMER" },
{276, "WM_HSCROLL" },
{277, "WM_VSCROLL" },
{278, "WM_INITMENU" },
{279, "WM_INITMENUPOPUP" },
{280, "WM_SYSTIMER" },
{287, "WM_MENUSELECT" },
{288, "WM_MENUCHAR" },
{289, "WM_ENTERIDLE" },
{290, "WM_MENURBUTTONUP" },
{291, "WM_MENUDRAG" },
{292, "WM_MENUGETOBJECT" },
{293, "WM_UNINITMENUPOPUP" },
{294, "WM_MENUCOMMAND" },
{295, "WM_CHANGEUISTATE" },
{296, "WM_UPDATEUISTATE" },
{297, "WM_QUERYUISTATE" },
{306, "WM_CTLCOLORMSGBOX" },
{307, "WM_CTLCOLOREDIT" },
{308, "WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX" },
{309, "WM_CTLCOLORBTN" },
{310, "WM_CTLCOLORDLG" },
{311, "WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR" },
{312, "WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC" },
{512, "WM_MOUSEFIRST" },
{512, "WM_MOUSEMOVE" },
{513, "WM_LBUTTONDOWN" },
{514, "WM_LBUTTONUP" },
{515, "WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK" },
{516, "WM_RBUTTONDOWN" },
{517, "WM_RBUTTONUP" },
{518, "WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK" },
{519, "WM_MBUTTONDOWN" },
{520, "WM_MBUTTONUP" },
{521, "WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK" },
{521, "WM_MOUSELAST" },
{522, "WM_MOUSEWHEEL" },
{523, "WM_XBUTTONDOWN" },
{524, "WM_XBUTTONUP" },
{525, "WM_XBUTTONDBLCLK" },
{528, "WM_PARENTNOTIFY" },
{529, "WM_ENTERMENULOOP" },
{530, "WM_EXITMENULOOP" },
{531, "WM_NEXTMENU" },
{532, "WM_SIZING" },
{533, "WM_CAPTURECHANGED" },
{534, "WM_MOVING" },
{536, "WM_POWERBROADCAST" },
{537, "WM_DEVICECHANGE" },
{544, "WM_MDICREATE" },
{545, "WM_MDIDESTROY" },
{546, "WM_MDIACTIVATE" },
{547, "WM_MDIRESTORE" },
{548, "WM_MDINEXT" },
{549, "WM_MDIMAXIMIZE" },
{550, "WM_MDITILE" },
{551, "WM_MDICASCADE" },
{552, "WM_MDIICONARRANGE" },
{553, "WM_MDIGETACTIVE" },
{560, "WM_MDISETMENU" },
{561, "WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE" },
{562, "WM_EXITSIZEMOVE" },
{563, "WM_DROPFILES" },
{564, "WM_MDIREFRESHMENU" },
{640, "WM_IME_REPORT" },
{641, "WM_IME_SETCONTEXT" },
{642, "WM_IME_NOTIFY" },
{643, "WM_IME_CONTROL" },
{644, "WM_IME_COMPOSITIONFULL" },
{645, "WM_IME_SELECT" },
{646, "WM_IME_CHAR" },
{648, "WM_IME_REQUEST" },
{656, "WM_IMEKEYDOWN" },
{656, "WM_IME_KEYDOWN" },
{657, "WM_IMEKEYUP" },
{657, "WM_IME_KEYUP" },
{672, "WM_NCMOUSEHOVER" },
{673, "WM_MOUSEHOVER" },
{674, "WM_NCMOUSELEAVE" },
{675, "WM_MOUSELEAVE" },
{768, "WM_CUT" },
{769, "WM_COPY" },
{770, "WM_PASTE" },
{771, "WM_CLEAR" },
{772, "WM_UNDO" },
{773, "WM_RENDERFORMAT" },
{774, "WM_RENDERALLFORMATS" },
{775, "WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD" },
{776, "WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD" },
{777, "WM_PAINTCLIPBOARD" },
{778, "WM_VSCROLLCLIPBOARD" },
{779, "WM_SIZECLIPBOARD" },
{780, "WM_ASKCBFORMATNAME" },
{781, "WM_CHANGECBCHAIN" },
{782, "WM_HSCROLLCLIPBOARD" },
{783, "WM_QUERYNEWPALETTE" },
{784, "WM_PALETTEISCHANGING" },
{785, "WM_PALETTECHANGED" },
{786, "WM_HOTKEY" },
{791, "WM_PRINT" },
{792, "WM_PRINTCLIENT" },
{793, "WM_APPCOMMAND" },
{856, "WM_HANDHELDFIRST" },
{863, "WM_HANDHELDLAST" },
{864, "WM_AFXFIRST" },
{895, "WM_AFXLAST" },
{896, "WM_PENWINFIRST" },
{897, "WM_RCRESULT" },
{898, "WM_HOOKRCRESULT" },
{899, "WM_GLOBALRCCHANGE" },
{899, "WM_PENMISCINFO" },
{900, "WM_SKB" },
{901, "WM_HEDITCTL" },
{901, "WM_PENCTL" },
{902, "WM_PENMISC" },
{903, "WM_CTLINIT" },
{904, "WM_PENEVENT" },
{911, "WM_PENWINLAST" },
{1024, "DDM_SETFMT" },
{1024, "DM_GETDEFID" },
{1024, "NIN_SELECT" },
{1024, "TBM_GETPOS" },
{1024, "WM_PSD_PAGESETUPDLG" },
{1024, "WM_USER" },
{1025, "CBEM_INSERTITEMA" },
{1025, "DDM_DRAW" },
{1025, "DM_SETDEFID" },
{1025, "HKM_SETHOTKEY" },
{1025, "PBM_SETRANGE" },
{1025, "RB_INSERTBANDA" },
{1025, "SB_SETTEXTA" },
{1025, "TB_ENABLEBUTTON" },
{1025, "TBM_GETRANGEMIN" },
{1025, "TTM_ACTIVATE" },
{1025, "WM_CHOOSEFONT_GETLOGFONT" },
{1025, "WM_PSD_FULLPAGERECT" },
{1026, "CBEM_SETIMAGELIST" },
{1026, "DDM_CLOSE" },
{1026, "DM_REPOSITION" },
{1026, "HKM_GETHOTKEY" },
{1026, "PBM_SETPOS" },
{1026, "RB_DELETEBAND" },
{1026, "SB_GETTEXTA" },
{1026, "TB_CHECKBUTTON" },
{1026, "TBM_GETRANGEMAX" },
{1026, "WM_PSD_MINMARGINRECT" },
{1027, "CBEM_GETIMAGELIST" },
{1027, "DDM_BEGIN" },
{1027, "HKM_SETRULES" },
{1027, "PBM_DELTAPOS" },
{1027, "RB_GETBARINFO" },
{1027, "SB_GETTEXTLENGTHA" },
{1027, "TBM_GETTIC" },
{1027, "TB_PRESSBUTTON" },
{1027, "TTM_SETDELAYTIME" },
{1027, "WM_PSD_MARGINRECT" },
{1028, "CBEM_GETITEMA" },
{1028, "DDM_END" },
{1028, "PBM_SETSTEP" },
{1028, "RB_SETBARINFO" },
{1028, "SB_SETPARTS" },
{1028, "TB_HIDEBUTTON" },
{1028, "TBM_SETTIC" },
{1028, "TTM_ADDTOOLA" },
{1028, "WM_PSD_GREEKTEXTRECT" },
{1029, "CBEM_SETITEMA" },
{1029, "PBM_STEPIT" },
{1029, "TB_INDETERMINATE" },
{1029, "TBM_SETPOS" },
{1029, "TTM_DELTOOLA" },
{1029, "WM_PSD_ENVSTAMPRECT" },
{1030, "CBEM_GETCOMBOCONTROL" },
{1030, "PBM_SETRANGE32" },
{1030, "RB_SETBANDINFOA" },
{1030, "SB_GETPARTS" },
{1030, "TB_MARKBUTTON" },
{1030, "TBM_SETRANGE" },
{1030, "TTM_NEWTOOLRECTA" },
{1030, "WM_PSD_YAFULLPAGERECT" },
{1031, "CBEM_GETEDITCONTROL" },
{1031, "PBM_GETRANGE" },
{1031, "RB_SETPARENT" },
{1031, "SB_GETBORDERS" },
{1031, "TBM_SETRANGEMIN" },
{1031, "TTM_RELAYEVENT" },
{1032, "CBEM_SETEXSTYLE" },
{1032, "PBM_GETPOS" },
{1032, "RB_HITTEST" },
{1032, "SB_SETMINHEIGHT" },
{1032, "TBM_SETRANGEMAX" },
{1032, "TTM_GETTOOLINFOA" },
{1033, "CBEM_GETEXSTYLE" },
{1033, "CBEM_GETEXTENDEDSTYLE" },
{1033, "PBM_SETBARCOLOR" },
{1033, "RB_GETRECT" },
{1033, "SB_SIMPLE" },
{1033, "TB_ISBUTTONENABLED" },
{1033, "TBM_CLEARTICS" },
{1033, "TTM_SETTOOLINFOA" },
{1034, "CBEM_HASEDITCHANGED" },
{1034, "RB_INSERTBANDW" },
{1034, "SB_GETRECT" },
{1034, "TB_ISBUTTONCHECKED" },
{1034, "TBM_SETSEL" },
{1034, "TTM_HITTESTA" },
{1034, "WIZ_QUERYNUMPAGES" },
{1035, "CBEM_INSERTITEMW" },
{1035, "RB_SETBANDINFOW" },
{1035, "SB_SETTEXTW" },
{1035, "TB_ISBUTTONPRESSED" },
{1035, "TBM_SETSELSTART" },
{1035, "TTM_GETTEXTA" },
{1035, "WIZ_NEXT" },
{1036, "CBEM_SETITEMW" },
{1036, "RB_GETBANDCOUNT" },
{1036, "SB_GETTEXTLENGTHW" },
{1036, "TB_ISBUTTONHIDDEN" },
{1036, "TBM_SETSELEND" },
{1036, "TTM_UPDATETIPTEXTA" },
{1036, "WIZ_PREV" },
{1037, "CBEM_GETITEMW" },
{1037, "RB_GETROWCOUNT" },
{1037, "SB_GETTEXTW" },
{1037, "TB_ISBUTTONINDETERMINATE" },
{1037, "TTM_GETTOOLCOUNT" },
{1038, "CBEM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE" },
{1038, "RB_GETROWHEIGHT" },
{1038, "SB_ISSIMPLE" },
{1038, "TB_ISBUTTONHIGHLIGHTED" },
{1038, "TBM_GETPTICS" },
{1038, "TTM_ENUMTOOLSA" },
{1039, "SB_SETICON" },
{1039, "TBM_GETTICPOS" },
{1039, "TTM_GETCURRENTTOOLA" },
{1040, "RB_IDTOINDEX" },
{1040, "SB_SETTIPTEXTA" },
{1040, "TBM_GETNUMTICS" },
{1040, "TTM_WINDOWFROMPOINT" },
{1041, "RB_GETTOOLTIPS" },
{1041, "SB_SETTIPTEXTW" },
{1041, "TBM_GETSELSTART" },
{1041, "TB_SETSTATE" },
{1041, "TTM_TRACKACTIVATE" },
{1042, "RB_SETTOOLTIPS" },
{1042, "SB_GETTIPTEXTA" },
{1042, "TB_GETSTATE" },
{1042, "TBM_GETSELEND" },
{1042, "TTM_TRACKPOSITION" },
{1043, "RB_SETBKCOLOR" },
{1043, "SB_GETTIPTEXTW" },
{1043, "TB_ADDBITMAP" },
{1043, "TBM_CLEARSEL" },
{1043, "TTM_SETTIPBKCOLOR" },
{1044, "RB_GETBKCOLOR" },
{1044, "SB_GETICON" },
{1044, "TB_ADDBUTTONSA" },
{1044, "TBM_SETTICFREQ" },
{1044, "TTM_SETTIPTEXTCOLOR" },
{1045, "RB_SETTEXTCOLOR" },
{1045, "TB_INSERTBUTTONA" },
{1045, "TBM_SETPAGESIZE" },
{1045, "TTM_GETDELAYTIME" },
{1046, "RB_GETTEXTCOLOR" },
{1046, "TB_DELETEBUTTON" },
{1046, "TBM_GETPAGESIZE" },
{1046, "TTM_GETTIPBKCOLOR" },
{1047, "RB_SIZETORECT" },
{1047, "TB_GETBUTTON" },
{1047, "TBM_SETLINESIZE" },
{1047, "TTM_GETTIPTEXTCOLOR" },
{1048, "RB_BEGINDRAG" },
{1048, "TB_BUTTONCOUNT" },
{1048, "TBM_GETLINESIZE" },
{1048, "TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH" },
{1049, "RB_ENDDRAG" },
{1049, "TB_COMMANDTOINDEX" },
{1049, "TBM_GETTHUMBRECT" },
{1049, "TTM_GETMAXTIPWIDTH" },
{1050, "RB_DRAGMOVE" },
{1050, "TBM_GETCHANNELRECT" },
{1050, "TB_SAVERESTOREA" },
{1050, "TTM_SETMARGIN" },
{1051, "RB_GETBARHEIGHT" },
{1051, "TB_CUSTOMIZE" },
{1051, "TBM_SETTHUMBLENGTH" },
{1051, "TTM_GETMARGIN" },
{1052, "RB_GETBANDINFOW" },
{1052, "TB_ADDSTRINGA" },
{1052, "TBM_GETTHUMBLENGTH" },
{1052, "TTM_POP" },
{1053, "RB_GETBANDINFOA" },
{1053, "TB_GETITEMRECT" },
{1053, "TBM_SETTOOLTIPS" },
{1053, "TTM_UPDATE" },
{1054, "RB_MINIMIZEBAND" },
{1054, "TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE" },
{1054, "TBM_GETTOOLTIPS" },
{1054, "TTM_GETBUBBLESIZE" },
{1055, "RB_MAXIMIZEBAND" },
{1055, "TBM_SETTIPSIDE" },
{1055, "TB_SETBUTTONSIZE" },
{1055, "TTM_ADJUSTRECT" },
{1056, "TBM_SETBUDDY" },
{1056, "TB_SETBITMAPSIZE" },
{1056, "TTM_SETTITLEA" },
{1057, "MSG_FTS_JUMP_VA" },
{1057, "TB_AUTOSIZE" },
{1057, "TBM_GETBUDDY" },
{1057, "TTM_SETTITLEW" },
{1058, "RB_GETBANDBORDERS" },
{1059, "MSG_FTS_JUMP_QWORD" },
{1059, "RB_SHOWBAND" },
{1059, "TB_GETTOOLTIPS" },
{1060, "MSG_REINDEX_REQUEST" },
{1060, "TB_SETTOOLTIPS" },
{1061, "MSG_FTS_WHERE_IS_IT" },
{1061, "RB_SETPALETTE" },
{1061, "TB_SETPARENT" },
{1062, "RB_GETPALETTE" },
{1063, "RB_MOVEBAND" },
{1063, "TB_SETROWS" },
{1064, "TB_GETROWS" },
{1065, "TB_GETBITMAPFLAGS" },
{1066, "TB_SETCMDID" },
{1067, "RB_PUSHCHEVRON" },
{1067, "TB_CHANGEBITMAP" },
{1068, "TB_GETBITMAP" },
{1069, "MSG_GET_DEFFONT" },
{1069, "TB_GETBUTTONTEXTA" },
{1070, "TB_REPLACEBITMAP" },
{1071, "TB_SETINDENT" },
{1072, "TB_SETIMAGELIST" },
{1073, "TB_GETIMAGELIST" },
{1074, "TB_LOADIMAGES" },
{1074, "EM_CANPASTE" },
{1074, "TTM_ADDTOOLW" },
{1075, "EM_DISPLAYBAND" },
{1075, "TB_GETRECT" },
{1075, "TTM_DELTOOLW" },
{1076, "EM_EXGETSEL" },
{1076, "TB_SETHOTIMAGELIST" },
{1076, "TTM_NEWTOOLRECTW" },
{1077, "EM_EXLIMITTEXT" },
{1077, "TB_GETHOTIMAGELIST" },
{1077, "TTM_GETTOOLINFOW" },
{1078, "EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR" },
{1078, "TB_SETDISABLEDIMAGELIST" },
{1078, "TTM_SETTOOLINFOW" },
{1079, "EM_EXSETSEL" },
{1079, "TB_GETDISABLEDIMAGELIST" },
{1079, "TTM_HITTESTW" },
{1080, "EM_FINDTEXT" },
{1080, "TB_SETSTYLE" },
{1080, "TTM_GETTEXTW" },
{1081, "EM_FORMATRANGE" },
{1081, "TB_GETSTYLE" },
{1081, "TTM_UPDATETIPTEXTW" },
{1082, "EM_GETCHARFORMAT" },
{1082, "TB_GETBUTTONSIZE" },
{1082, "TTM_ENUMTOOLSW" },
{1083, "EM_GETEVENTMASK" },
{1083, "TB_SETBUTTONWIDTH" },
{1083, "TTM_GETCURRENTTOOLW" },
{1084, "EM_GETOLEINTERFACE" },
{1084, "TB_SETMAXTEXTROWS" },
{1085, "EM_GETPARAFORMAT" },
{1085, "TB_GETTEXTROWS" },
{1086, "EM_GETSELTEXT" },
{1086, "TB_GETOBJECT" },
{1087, "EM_HIDESELECTION" },
{1087, "TB_GETBUTTONINFOW" },
{1088, "EM_PASTESPECIAL" },
{1088, "TB_SETBUTTONINFOW" },
{1089, "EM_REQUESTRESIZE" },
{1089, "TB_GETBUTTONINFOA" },
{1090, "EM_SELECTIONTYPE" },
{1090, "TB_SETBUTTONINFOA" },
{1091, "EM_SETBKGNDCOLOR" },
{1091, "TB_INSERTBUTTONW" },
{1092, "EM_SETCHARFORMAT" },
{1092, "TB_ADDBUTTONSW" },
{1093, "EM_SETEVENTMASK" },
{1093, "TB_HITTEST" },
{1094, "EM_SETOLECALLBACK" },
{1094, "TB_SETDRAWTEXTFLAGS" },
{1095, "EM_SETPARAFORMAT" },
{1095, "TB_GETHOTITEM" },
{1096, "EM_SETTARGETDEVICE" },
{1096, "TB_SETHOTITEM" },
{1097, "EM_STREAMIN" },
{1097, "TB_SETANCHORHIGHLIGHT" },
{1098, "EM_STREAMOUT" },
{1098, "TB_GETANCHORHIGHLIGHT" },
{1099, "EM_GETTEXTRANGE" },
{1099, "TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW" },
{1100, "EM_FINDWORDBREAK" },
{1100, "TB_SAVERESTOREW" },
{1101, "EM_SETOPTIONS" },
{1101, "TB_ADDSTRINGW" },
{1102, "EM_GETOPTIONS" },
{1102, "TB_MAPACCELERATORA" },
{1103, "EM_FINDTEXTEX" },
{1103, "TB_GETINSERTMARK" },
{1104, "EM_GETWORDBREAKPROCEX" },
{1104, "TB_SETINSERTMARK" },
{1105, "EM_SETWORDBREAKPROCEX" },
{1105, "TB_INSERTMARKHITTEST" },
{1106, "EM_SETUNDOLIMIT" },
{1106, "TB_MOVEBUTTON" },
{1107, "TB_GETMAXSIZE" },
{1108, "EM_REDO" },
{1108, "TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE" },
{1109, "EM_CANREDO" },
{1109, "TB_GETEXTENDEDSTYLE" },
{1110, "EM_GETUNDONAME" },
{1110, "TB_GETPADDING" },
{1111, "EM_GETREDONAME" },
{1111, "TB_SETPADDING" },
{1112, "EM_STOPGROUPTYPING" },
{1112, "TB_SETINSERTMARKCOLOR" },
{1113, "EM_SETTEXTMODE" },
{1113, "TB_GETINSERTMARKCOLOR" },
{1114, "EM_GETTEXTMODE" },
{1114, "TB_MAPACCELERATORW" },
{1115, "EM_AUTOURLDETECT" },
{1115, "TB_GETSTRINGW" },
{1116, "EM_GETAUTOURLDETECT" },
{1116, "TB_GETSTRINGA" },
{1117, "EM_SETPALETTE" },
{1118, "EM_GETTEXTEX" },
{1119, "EM_GETTEXTLENGTHEX" },
{1120, "EM_SHOWSCROLLBAR" },
{1121, "EM_SETTEXTEX" },
{1123, "TAPI_REPLY" },
{1124, "ACM_OPENA" },
{1124, "BFFM_SETSTATUSTEXTA" },
{1124, "CDM_FIRST" },
{1124, "CDM_GETSPEC" },
{1124, "EM_SETPUNCTUATION" },
{1124, "IPM_CLEARADDRESS" },
{1124, "WM_CAP_UNICODE_START" },
{1125, "ACM_PLAY" },
{1125, "BFFM_ENABLEOK" },
{1125, "CDM_GETFILEPATH" },
{1125, "EM_GETPUNCTUATION" },
{1125, "IPM_SETADDRESS" },
{1125, "PSM_SETCURSEL" },
{1125, "UDM_SETRANGE" },
{1125, "WM_CHOOSEFONT_SETLOGFONT" },
{1126, "ACM_STOP" },
{1126, "BFFM_SETSELECTIONA" },
{1126, "CDM_GETFOLDERPATH" },
{1126, "EM_SETWORDWRAPMODE" },
{1126, "IPM_GETADDRESS" },
{1126, "PSM_REMOVEPAGE" },
{1126, "UDM_GETRANGE" },
{1126, "WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_ERRORW" },
{1126, "WM_CHOOSEFONT_SETFLAGS" },
{1127, "ACM_OPENW" },
{1127, "BFFM_SETSELECTIONW" },
{1127, "CDM_GETFOLDERIDLIST" },
{1127, "EM_GETWORDWRAPMODE" },
{1127, "IPM_SETRANGE" },
{1127, "PSM_ADDPAGE" },
{1127, "UDM_SETPOS" },
{1127, "WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_STATUSW" },
{1128, "BFFM_SETSTATUSTEXTW" },
{1128, "CDM_SETCONTROLTEXT" },
{1128, "EM_SETIMECOLOR" },
{1128, "IPM_SETFOCUS" },
{1128, "PSM_CHANGED" },
{1128, "UDM_GETPOS" },
{1129, "CDM_HIDECONTROL" },
{1129, "EM_GETIMECOLOR" },
{1129, "IPM_ISBLANK" },
{1129, "PSM_RESTARTWINDOWS" },
{1129, "UDM_SETBUDDY" },
{1130, "CDM_SETDEFEXT" },
{1130, "EM_SETIMEOPTIONS" },
{1130, "PSM_REBOOTSYSTEM" },
{1130, "UDM_GETBUDDY" },
{1131, "EM_GETIMEOPTIONS" },
{1131, "PSM_CANCELTOCLOSE" },
{1131, "UDM_SETACCEL" },
{1132, "EM_CONVPOSITION" },
{1132, "EM_CONVPOSITION" },
{1132, "PSM_QUERYSIBLINGS" },
{1132, "UDM_GETACCEL" },
{1133, "MCIWNDM_GETZOOM" },
{1133, "PSM_UNCHANGED" },
{1133, "UDM_SETBASE" },
{1134, "PSM_APPLY" },
{1134, "UDM_GETBASE" },
{1135, "PSM_SETTITLEA" },
{1135, "UDM_SETRANGE32" },
{1136, "PSM_SETWIZBUTTONS" },
{1136, "UDM_GETRANGE32" },
{1136, "WM_CAP_DRIVER_GET_NAMEW" },
{1137, "PSM_PRESSBUTTON" },
{1137, "UDM_SETPOS32" },
{1137, "WM_CAP_DRIVER_GET_VERSIONW" },
{1138, "PSM_SETCURSELID" },
{1138, "UDM_GETPOS32" },
{1139, "PSM_SETFINISHTEXTA" },
{1140, "PSM_GETTABCONTROL" },
{1141, "PSM_ISDIALOGMESSAGE" },
{1142, "MCIWNDM_REALIZE" },
{1142, "PSM_GETCURRENTPAGEHWND" },
{1143, "MCIWNDM_SETTIMEFORMATA" },
{1143, "PSM_INSERTPAGE" },
{1144, "EM_SETLANGOPTIONS" },
{1144, "MCIWNDM_GETTIMEFORMATA" },
{1144, "PSM_SETTITLEW" },
{1144, "WM_CAP_FILE_SET_CAPTURE_FILEW" },
{1145, "EM_GETLANGOPTIONS" },
{1145, "MCIWNDM_VALIDATEMEDIA" },
{1145, "PSM_SETFINISHTEXTW" },
{1145, "WM_CAP_FILE_GET_CAPTURE_FILEW" },
{1146, "EM_GETIMECOMPMODE" },
{1147, "EM_FINDTEXTW" },
{1147, "MCIWNDM_PLAYTO" },
{1147, "WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEASW" },
{1148, "EM_FINDTEXTEXW" },
{1148, "MCIWNDM_GETFILENAMEA" },
{1149, "EM_RECONVERSION" },
{1149, "MCIWNDM_GETDEVICEA" },
{1149, "PSM_SETHEADERTITLEA" },
{1149, "WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIBW" },
{1150, "EM_SETIMEMODEBIAS" },
{1150, "MCIWNDM_GETPALETTE" },
{1150, "PSM_SETHEADERTITLEW" },
{1151, "EM_GETIMEMODEBIAS" },
{1151, "MCIWNDM_SETPALETTE" },
{1151, "PSM_SETHEADERSUBTITLEA" },
{1152, "MCIWNDM_GETERRORA" },
{1152, "PSM_SETHEADERSUBTITLEW" },
{1153, "PSM_HWNDTOINDEX" },
{1154, "PSM_INDEXTOHWND" },
{1155, "MCIWNDM_SETINACTIVETIMER" },
{1155, "PSM_PAGETOINDEX" },
{1156, "PSM_INDEXTOPAGE" },
{1157, "DL_BEGINDRAG" },
{1157, "MCIWNDM_GETINACTIVETIMER" },
{1157, "PSM_IDTOINDEX" },
{1158, "DL_DRAGGING" },
{1158, "PSM_INDEXTOID" },
{1159, "DL_DROPPED" },
{1159, "PSM_GETRESULT" },
{1160, "DL_CANCELDRAG" },
{1160, "PSM_RECALCPAGESIZES" },
{1164, "MCIWNDM_GET_SOURCE" },
{1165, "MCIWNDM_PUT_SOURCE" },
{1166, "MCIWNDM_GET_DEST" },
{1167, "MCIWNDM_PUT_DEST" },
{1168, "MCIWNDM_CAN_PLAY" },
{1169, "MCIWNDM_CAN_WINDOW" },
{1170, "MCIWNDM_CAN_RECORD" },
{1171, "MCIWNDM_CAN_SAVE" },
{1172, "MCIWNDM_CAN_EJECT" },
{1173, "MCIWNDM_CAN_CONFIG" },
{1174, "IE_GETINK" },
{1174, "IE_MSGFIRST" },
{1174, "MCIWNDM_PALETTEKICK" },
{1175, "IE_SETINK" },
{1176, "IE_GETPENTIP" },
{1177, "IE_SETPENTIP" },
{1178, "IE_GETERASERTIP" },
{1179, "IE_SETERASERTIP" },
{1180, "IE_GETBKGND" },
{1181, "IE_SETBKGND" },
{1182, "IE_GETGRIDORIGIN" },
{1183, "IE_SETGRIDORIGIN" },
{1184, "IE_GETGRIDPEN" },
{1185, "IE_SETGRIDPEN" },
{1186, "IE_GETGRIDSIZE" },
{1187, "IE_SETGRIDSIZE" },
{1188, "IE_GETMODE" },
{1189, "IE_SETMODE" },
{1190, "IE_GETINKRECT" },
{1190, "WM_CAP_SET_MCI_DEVICEW" },
{1191, "WM_CAP_GET_MCI_DEVICEW" },
{1204, "WM_CAP_PAL_OPENW" },
{1205, "WM_CAP_PAL_SAVEW" },
{1208, "IE_GETAPPDATA" },
{1209, "IE_SETAPPDATA" },
{1210, "IE_GETDRAWOPTS" },
{1211, "IE_SETDRAWOPTS" },
{1212, "IE_GETFORMAT" },
{1213, "IE_SETFORMAT" },
{1214, "IE_GETINKINPUT" },
{1215, "IE_SETINKINPUT" },
{1216, "IE_GETNOTIFY" },
{1217, "IE_SETNOTIFY" },
{1218, "IE_GETRECOG" },
{1219, "IE_SETRECOG" },
{1220, "IE_GETSECURITY" },
{1221, "IE_SETSECURITY" },
{1222, "IE_GETSEL" },
{1223, "IE_SETSEL" },
{1224, "CDM_LAST" },
{1224, "EM_SETBIDIOPTIONS" },
{1224, "IE_DOCOMMAND" },
{1224, "MCIWNDM_NOTIFYMODE" },
{1225, "EM_GETBIDIOPTIONS" },
{1225, "IE_GETCOMMAND" },
{1226, "EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS" },
{1226, "IE_GETCOUNT" },
{1227, "EM_GETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS" },
{1227, "IE_GETGESTURE" },
{1227, "MCIWNDM_NOTIFYMEDIA" },
{1228, "EM_SETEDITSTYLE" },
{1228, "IE_GETMENU" },
{1229, "EM_GETEDITSTYLE" },
{1229, "IE_GETPAINTDC" },
{1229, "MCIWNDM_NOTIFYERROR" },
{1230, "IE_GETPDEVENT" },
{1231, "IE_GETSELCOUNT" },
{1232, "IE_GETSELITEMS" },
{1233, "IE_GETSTYLE" },
{1243, "MCIWNDM_SETTIMEFORMATW" },
{1244, "EM_OUTLINE" },
{1244, "EM_OUTLINE" },
{1244, "MCIWNDM_GETTIMEFORMATW" },
{1245, "EM_GETSCROLLPOS" },
{1245, "EM_GETSCROLLPOS" },
{1246, "EM_SETSCROLLPOS" },
{1246, "EM_SETSCROLLPOS" },
{1247, "EM_SETFONTSIZE" },
{1247, "EM_SETFONTSIZE" },
{1248, "EM_GETZOOM" },
{1248, "MCIWNDM_GETFILENAMEW" },
{1249, "EM_SETZOOM" },
{1249, "MCIWNDM_GETDEVICEW" },
{1250, "EM_GETVIEWKIND" },
{1251, "EM_SETVIEWKIND" },
{1252, "EM_GETPAGE" },
{1252, "MCIWNDM_GETERRORW" },
{1253, "EM_SETPAGE" },
{1254, "EM_GETHYPHENATEINFO" },
{1255, "EM_SETHYPHENATEINFO" },
{1259, "EM_GETPAGEROTATE" },
{1260, "EM_SETPAGEROTATE" },
{1261, "EM_GETCTFMODEBIAS" },
{1262, "EM_SETCTFMODEBIAS" },
{1264, "EM_GETCTFOPENSTATUS" },
{1265, "EM_SETCTFOPENSTATUS" },
{1266, "EM_GETIMECOMPTEXT" },
{1267, "EM_ISIME" },
{1268, "EM_GETIMEPROPERTY" },
{1293, "EM_GETQUERYRTFOBJ" },
{1294, "EM_SETQUERYRTFOBJ" },
{1536, "FM_GETFOCUS" },
{1537, "FM_GETDRIVEINFOA" },
{1538, "FM_GETSELCOUNT" },
{1539, "FM_GETSELCOUNTLFN" },
{1540, "FM_GETFILESELA" },
{1541, "FM_GETFILESELLFNA" },
{1542, "FM_REFRESH_WINDOWS" },
{1543, "FM_RELOAD_EXTENSIONS" },
{1553, "FM_GETDRIVEINFOW" },
{1556, "FM_GETFILESELW" },
{1557, "FM_GETFILESELLFNW" },
{1625, "WLX_WM_SAS" },
{2024, "SM_GETSELCOUNT" },
{2024, "UM_GETSELCOUNT" },
{2024, "WM_CPL_LAUNCH" },
{2025, "SM_GETSERVERSELA" },
{2025, "UM_GETUSERSELA" },
{2025, "WM_CPL_LAUNCHED" },
{2026, "SM_GETSERVERSELW" },
{2026, "UM_GETUSERSELW" },
{2027, "SM_GETCURFOCUSA" },
{2027, "UM_GETGROUPSELA" },
{2028, "SM_GETCURFOCUSW" },
{2028, "UM_GETGROUPSELW" },
{2029, "SM_GETOPTIONS" },
{2029, "UM_GETCURFOCUSA" },
{2030, "UM_GETCURFOCUSW" },
{2031, "UM_GETOPTIONS" },
{2032, "UM_GETOPTIONS2" },
{4096, "LVM_FIRST" },
{4096, "LVM_GETBKCOLOR" },
{4097, "LVM_SETBKCOLOR" },
{4098, "LVM_GETIMAGELIST" },
{4099, "LVM_SETIMAGELIST" },
{4100, "LVM_GETITEMCOUNT" },
{4101, "LVM_GETITEMA" },
{4102, "LVM_SETITEMA" },
{4103, "LVM_INSERTITEMA" },
{4104, "LVM_DELETEITEM" },
{4105, "LVM_DELETEALLITEMS" },
{4106, "LVM_GETCALLBACKMASK" },
{4107, "LVM_SETCALLBACKMASK" },
{4108, "LVM_GETNEXTITEM" },
{4109, "LVM_FINDITEMA" },
{4110, "LVM_GETITEMRECT" },
{4111, "LVM_SETITEMPOSITION" },
{4112, "LVM_GETITEMPOSITION" },
{4113, "LVM_GETSTRINGWIDTHA" },
{4114, "LVM_HITTEST" },
{4115, "LVM_ENSUREVISIBLE" },
{4116, "LVM_SCROLL" },
{4117, "LVM_REDRAWITEMS" },
{4118, "LVM_ARRANGE" },
{4119, "LVM_EDITLABELA" },
{4120, "LVM_GETEDITCONTROL" },
{4121, "LVM_GETCOLUMNA" },
{4122, "LVM_SETCOLUMNA" },
{4123, "LVM_INSERTCOLUMNA" },
{4124, "LVM_DELETECOLUMN" },
{4125, "LVM_GETCOLUMNWIDTH" },
{4126, "LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH" },
{4127, "LVM_GETHEADER" },
{4129, "LVM_CREATEDRAGIMAGE" },
{4130, "LVM_GETVIEWRECT" },
{4131, "LVM_GETTEXTCOLOR" },
{4132, "LVM_SETTEXTCOLOR" },
{4133, "LVM_GETTEXTBKCOLOR" },
{4134, "LVM_SETTEXTBKCOLOR" },
{4135, "LVM_GETTOPINDEX" },
{4136, "LVM_GETCOUNTPERPAGE" },
{4137, "LVM_GETORIGIN" },
{4138, "LVM_UPDATE" },
{4139, "LVM_SETITEMSTATE" },
{4140, "LVM_GETITEMSTATE" },
{4141, "LVM_GETITEMTEXTA" },
{4142, "LVM_SETITEMTEXTA" },
{4143, "LVM_SETITEMCOUNT" },
{4144, "LVM_SORTITEMS" },
{4145, "LVM_SETITEMPOSITION32" },
{4146, "LVM_GETSELECTEDCOUNT" },
{4147, "LVM_GETITEMSPACING" },
{4148, "LVM_GETISEARCHSTRINGA" },
{4149, "LVM_SETICONSPACING" },
{4150, "LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE" },
{4151, "LVM_GETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE" },
{4152, "LVM_GETSUBITEMRECT" },
{4153, "LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST" },
{4154, "LVM_SETCOLUMNORDERARRAY" },
{4155, "LVM_GETCOLUMNORDERARRAY" },
{4156, "LVM_SETHOTITEM" },
{4157, "LVM_GETHOTITEM" },
{4158, "LVM_SETHOTCURSOR" },
{4159, "LVM_GETHOTCURSOR" },
{4160, "LVM_APPROXIMATEVIEWRECT" },
{4161, "LVM_SETWORKAREAS" },
{4162, "LVM_GETSELECTIONMARK" },
{4163, "LVM_SETSELECTIONMARK" },
{4164, "LVM_SETBKIMAGEA" },
{4165, "LVM_GETBKIMAGEA" },
{4166, "LVM_GETWORKAREAS" },
{4167, "LVM_SETHOVERTIME" },
{4168, "LVM_GETHOVERTIME" },
{4169, "LVM_GETNUMBEROFWORKAREAS" },
{4170, "LVM_SETTOOLTIPS" },
{4171, "LVM_GETITEMW" },
{4172, "LVM_SETITEMW" },
{4173, "LVM_INSERTITEMW" },
{4174, "LVM_GETTOOLTIPS" },
{4179, "LVM_FINDITEMW" },
{4183, "LVM_GETSTRINGWIDTHW" },
{4191, "LVM_GETCOLUMNW" },
{4192, "LVM_SETCOLUMNW" },
{4193, "LVM_INSERTCOLUMNW" },
{4211, "LVM_GETITEMTEXTW" },
{4212, "LVM_SETITEMTEXTW" },
{4213, "LVM_GETISEARCHSTRINGW" },
{4214, "LVM_EDITLABELW" },
{4235, "LVM_GETBKIMAGEW" },
{4236, "LVM_SETSELECTEDCOLUMN" },
{4237, "LVM_SETTILEWIDTH" },
{4238, "LVM_SETVIEW" },
{4239, "LVM_GETVIEW" },
{4241, "LVM_INSERTGROUP" },
{4243, "LVM_SETGROUPINFO" },
{4245, "LVM_GETGROUPINFO" },
{4246, "LVM_REMOVEGROUP" },
{4247, "LVM_MOVEGROUP" },
{4250, "LVM_MOVEITEMTOGROUP" },
{4251, "LVM_SETGROUPMETRICS" },
{4252, "LVM_GETGROUPMETRICS" },
{4253, "LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW" },
{4254, "LVM_SORTGROUPS" },
{4255, "LVM_INSERTGROUPSORTED" },
{4256, "LVM_REMOVEALLGROUPS" },
{4257, "LVM_HASGROUP" },
{4258, "LVM_SETTILEVIEWINFO" },
{4259, "LVM_GETTILEVIEWINFO" },
{4260, "LVM_SETTILEINFO" },
{4261, "LVM_GETTILEINFO" },
{4262, "LVM_SETINSERTMARK" },
{4263, "LVM_GETINSERTMARK" },
{4264, "LVM_INSERTMARKHITTEST" },
{4265, "LVM_GETINSERTMARKRECT" },
{4266, "LVM_SETINSERTMARKCOLOR" },
{4267, "LVM_GETINSERTMARKCOLOR" },
{4269, "LVM_SETINFOTIP" },
{4270, "LVM_GETSELECTEDCOLUMN" },
{4271, "LVM_ISGROUPVIEWENABLED" },
{4272, "LVM_GETOUTLINECOLOR" },
{4273, "LVM_SETOUTLINECOLOR" },
{4275, "LVM_CANCELEDITLABEL" },
{4276, "LVM_MAPINDEXTOID" },
{4277, "LVM_MAPIDTOINDEX" },
{4278, "LVM_ISITEMVISIBLE" },
{8192, "OCM__BASE" },
{8197, "LVM_SETUNICODEFORMAT" },
{8198, "LVM_GETUNICODEFORMAT" },
{8217, "OCM_CTLCOLOR" },
{8235, "OCM_DRAWITEM" },
{8236, "OCM_MEASUREITEM" },
{8237, "OCM_DELETEITEM" },
{8238, "OCM_VKEYTOITEM" },
{8239, "OCM_CHARTOITEM" },
{8249, "OCM_COMPAREITEM" },
{8270, "OCM_NOTIFY" },
{8465, "OCM_COMMAND" },
{8468, "OCM_HSCROLL" },
{8469, "OCM_VSCROLL" },
{8498, "OCM_CTLCOLORMSGBOX" },
{8499, "OCM_CTLCOLOREDIT" },
{8500, "OCM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX" },
{8501, "OCM_CTLCOLORBTN" },
{8502, "OCM_CTLCOLORDLG" },
{8503, "OCM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR" },
{8504, "OCM_CTLCOLORSTATIC" },
{8720, "OCM_PARENTNOTIFY" },
{32768, "WM_APP" },
{52429, "WM_RASDIALEVENT" },
};
```

**NOTE:**

- There are some duplicates in the list, which i did not remove.
- std::map discards them automatically...

Comment: Didn't compile for me with VS2013. Had to change `wchar_t*` to `const char*`, since the map is initialized with single-byte strings. Changing to `L"Wide string literals"` might also help.

Comment: This should not be an answer, it is a copy paste from https://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages and has not been checked at all. It contains duplicates, if converted to a map in any language it will have a duplicate key exception. There many items as such.

Comment: @MarinoŠimić Duplicates won't cause an exception in C++ map initialization. It just discards duplicates (see [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffbf1fc25ad5a547)). Nevertheless, a better data type would be `std::multimap`, which allows a M:N mapping.

Comment: @MarinoŠimić Your comment should not be a comment; it adds nothing to the discussion and just distracts and wastes everyone's time. The answer was useful to me, and judging by the upvote count, many others as well.

Comment: @chili if you copy pasted this into your code beware of duplicates that are not duplicates. I did not post my comment for nothing. Just one example:
{209, "EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC" },
{209, "EM_GETWORDBREAKPROC" },

GET AND SET with the same ID.... with the std::map you will loose the first one, in other languages this will give an exception, which would be preferable to simply silenty swallowing items.

Answer (score 11):

There is no function as far as I know, but you can make one relatively easily. You need to copy all the message definitions from Windows.h and put them in a C++ file like this:

```
#define X(x) { x, #x },
struct WindowsMessage
{
    int msgid;
    char* pname;
} WindowsMessages[] =
{
    X( WM_PAINT )
    X( WM_NCPAINT )
    ...
};
#undef X
```

Then you write a function which, given a message id, searches through this table and returns the corresponding text. `#` in the macro is the famous "stringize" operator of C, which converts the identifier that follows it into a string literal. How convenient!

Comment: I've done this before but did it the hard way by copying the whole block of constants and putting quotes around them, etc.  This approach is much cleaner.

Comment: Yes, and do not forget that Visual Studio has block-mode editing capabilities, (Alt+mouse, and as of VS2010 Alt+Shift+cursor keys) which make that kind of stuff a lot easier.

Comment: Here is a handy list of windows messages, to save you poking around in windows.h: http://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages

Answer (score 3):

```
// https://rextester.com/DVKG30016
#include <iostream>

const char*id2str_impl(int id){
  #define F(A,B)case A:return #B;
  switch(id){
    F(0,WM_NULL)
    F(1,WM_CREATE)
    F(2,WM_DESTROY)
    F(3,WM_MOVE)
    F(5,WM_SIZE)
    F(6,WM_ACTIVATE)
    F(7,WM_SETFOCUS)
    F(8,WM_KILLFOCUS)
    F(10,WM_ENABLE)
    F(11,WM_SETREDRAW)
    F(12,WM_SETTEXT)
    F(13,WM_GETTEXT)
    F(14,WM_GETTEXTLENGTH)
    F(15,WM_PAINT)
    F(16,WM_CLOSE)
    F(17,WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
    F(18,WM_QUIT)
    F(19,WM_QUERYOPEN)
    F(20,WM_ERASEBKGND)
    F(21,WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE)
    F(22,WM_ENDSESSION)
    F(24,WM_SHOWWINDOW)
    F(25,WM_CTLCOLOR)
    F(26,WM_WININICHANGE)
    F(27,WM_DEVMODECHANGE)
    F(28,WM_ACTIVATEAPP)
    F(29,WM_FONTCHANGE)
    F(30,WM_TIMECHANGE)
    F(31,WM_CANCELMODE)
    F(32,WM_SETCURSOR)
    F(33,WM_MOUSEACTIVATE)
    F(34,WM_CHILDACTIVATE)
    F(35,WM_QUEUESYNC)
    F(36,WM_GETMINMAXINFO)
    F(38,WM_PAINTICON)
    F(39,WM_ICONERASEBKGND)
    F(40,WM_NEXTDLGCTL)
    F(42,WM_SPOOLERSTATUS)
    F(43,WM_DRAWITEM)
    F(44,WM_MEASUREITEM)
    F(45,WM_DELETEITEM)
    F(46,WM_VKEYTOITEM)
    F(47,WM_CHARTOITEM)
    F(48,WM_SETFONT)
    F(49,WM_GETFONT)
    F(50,WM_SETHOTKEY)
    F(51,WM_GETHOTKEY)
    F(55,WM_QUERYDRAGICON)
    F(57,WM_COMPAREITEM)
    F(61,WM_GETOBJECT)
    F(65,WM_COMPACTING)
    F(68,WM_COMMNOTIFY)
    F(70,WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING)
    F(71,WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED)
    F(72,WM_POWER)
    F(73,WM_COPYGLOBALDATA)
    F(74,WM_COPYDATA)
    F(75,WM_CANCELJOURNAL)
    F(78,WM_NOTIFY)
    F(80,WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST)
    F(81,WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE)
    F(82,WM_TCARD)
    F(83,WM_HELP)
    F(84,WM_USERCHANGED)
    F(85,WM_NOTIFYFORMAT)
    F(123,WM_CONTEXTMENU)
    F(124,WM_STYLECHANGING)
    F(125,WM_STYLECHANGED)
    F(126,WM_DISPLAYCHANGE)
    F(127,WM_GETICON)
    F(128,WM_SETICON)
    F(129,WM_NCCREATE)
    F(130,WM_NCDESTROY)
    F(131,WM_NCCALCSIZE)
    F(132,WM_NCHITTEST)
    F(133,WM_NCPAINT)
    F(134,WM_NCACTIVATE)
    F(135,WM_GETDLGCODE)
    F(136,WM_SYNCPAINT)
    F(160,WM_NCMOUSEMOVE)
    F(161,WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN)
    F(162,WM_NCLBUTTONUP)
    F(163,WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
    F(164,WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN)
    F(165,WM_NCRBUTTONUP)
    F(166,WM_NCRBUTTONDBLCLK)
    F(167,WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN)
    F(168,WM_NCMBUTTONUP)
    F(169,WM_NCMBUTTONDBLCLK)
    F(171,WM_NCXBUTTONDOWN)
    F(172,WM_NCXBUTTONUP)
    F(173,WM_NCXBUTTONDBLCLK)
    F(176,EM_GETSEL)
    F(177,EM_SETSEL)
    F(178,EM_GETRECT)
    F(179,EM_SETRECT)
    F(180,EM_SETRECTNP)
    F(181,EM_SCROLL)
    F(182,EM_LINESCROLL)
    F(183,EM_SCROLLCARET)
    F(185,EM_GETMODIFY)
    F(187,EM_SETMODIFY)
    F(188,EM_GETLINECOUNT)
    F(189,EM_LINEINDEX)
    F(190,EM_SETHANDLE)
    F(191,EM_GETHANDLE)
    F(192,EM_GETTHUMB)
    F(193,EM_LINELENGTH)
    F(194,EM_REPLACESEL)
    F(195,EM_SETFONT)
    F(196,EM_GETLINE)
    F(197,(EM_LIMITTEXT,EM_SETLIMITTEXT))
    F(198,EM_CANUNDO)
    F(199,EM_UNDO)
    F(200,EM_FMTLINES)
    F(201,EM_LINEFROMCHAR)
    F(202,EM_SETWORDBREAK)
    F(203,EM_SETTABSTOPS)
    F(204,EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR)
    F(205,EM_EMPTYUNDOBUFFER)
    F(206,EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE)
    F(207,EM_SETREADONLY)
    F(209,(EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC,EM_GETWORDBREAKPROC))
    F(210,EM_GETPASSWORDCHAR)
    F(211,EM_SETMARGINS)
    F(212,EM_GETMARGINS)
    F(213,EM_GETLIMITTEXT)
    F(214,EM_POSFROMCHAR)
    F(215,EM_CHARFROMPOS)
    F(216,EM_SETIMESTATUS)
    F(217,EM_GETIMESTATUS)
    F(224,SBM_SETPOS)
    F(225,SBM_GETPOS)
    F(226,SBM_SETRANGE)
    F(227,SBM_GETRANGE)
    F(228,SBM_ENABLE_ARROWS)
    F(230,SBM_SETRANGEREDRAW)
    F(233,SBM_SETSCROLLINFO)
    F(234,SBM_GETSCROLLINFO)
    F(235,SBM_GETSCROLLBARINFO)
    F(240,BM_GETCHECK)
    F(241,BM_SETCHECK)
    F(242,BM_GETSTATE)
    F(243,BM_SETSTATE)
    F(244,BM_SETSTYLE)
    F(245,BM_CLICK)
    F(246,BM_GETIMAGE)
    F(247,BM_SETIMAGE)
    F(248,BM_SETDONTCLICK)
    F(255,WM_INPUT)
    F(256,WM_KEYDOWN)
    F(257,WM_KEYUP)
    F(258,WM_CHAR)
    F(259,WM_DEADCHAR)
    F(260,WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
    F(261,WM_SYSKEYUP)
    F(262,WM_SYSCHAR)
    F(263,WM_SYSDEADCHAR)
    F(265,(WM_UNICHAR,WM_WNT_CONVERTREQUESTEX))
    F(266,WM_CONVERTREQUEST)
    F(267,WM_CONVERTRESULT)
    F(268,WM_INTERIM)
    F(269,WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION)
    F(270,WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION)
    F(271,WM_IME_COMPOSITION)
    F(272,WM_INITDIALOG)
    F(273,WM_COMMAND)
    F(274,WM_SYSCOMMAND)
    F(275,WM_TIMER)
    F(276,WM_HSCROLL)
    F(277,WM_VSCROLL)
    F(278,WM_INITMENU)
    F(279,WM_INITMENUPOPUP)
    F(280,WM_SYSTIMER)
    F(287,WM_MENUSELECT)
    F(288,WM_MENUCHAR)
    F(289,WM_ENTERIDLE)
    F(290,WM_MENURBUTTONUP)
    F(291,WM_MENUDRAG)
    F(292,WM_MENUGETOBJECT)
    F(293,WM_UNINITMENUPOPUP)
    F(294,WM_MENUCOMMAND)
    F(295,WM_CHANGEUISTATE)
    F(296,WM_UPDATEUISTATE)
    F(297,WM_QUERYUISTATE)
    F(306,WM_CTLCOLORMSGBOX)
    F(307,WM_CTLCOLOREDIT)
    F(308,WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX)
    F(309,WM_CTLCOLORBTN)
    F(310,WM_CTLCOLORDLG)
    F(311,WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR)
    F(312,WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC)
    F(512,WM_MOUSEMOVE)
    F(513,WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    F(514,WM_LBUTTONUP)
    F(515,WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
    F(516,WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
    F(517,WM_RBUTTONUP)
    F(518,WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK)
    F(519,WM_MBUTTONDOWN)
    F(520,WM_MBUTTONUP)
    F(521,WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK)
    F(522,WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
    F(523,WM_XBUTTONDOWN)
    F(524,WM_XBUTTONUP)
    F(525,WM_XBUTTONDBLCLK)
    F(526,WM_MOUSEHWHEEL)
    F(528,WM_PARENTNOTIFY)
    F(529,WM_ENTERMENULOOP)
    F(530,WM_EXITMENULOOP)
    F(531,WM_NEXTMENU)
    F(532,WM_SIZING)
    F(533,WM_CAPTURECHANGED)
    F(534,WM_MOVING)
    F(536,WM_POWERBROADCAST)
    F(537,WM_DEVICECHANGE)
    F(544,WM_MDICREATE)
    F(545,WM_MDIDESTROY)
    F(546,WM_MDIACTIVATE)
    F(547,WM_MDIRESTORE)
    F(548,WM_MDINEXT)
    F(549,WM_MDIMAXIMIZE)
    F(550,WM_MDITILE)
    F(551,WM_MDICASCADE)
    F(552,WM_MDIICONARRANGE)
    F(553,WM_MDIGETACTIVE)
    F(560,WM_MDISETMENU)
    F(561,WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE)
    F(562,WM_EXITSIZEMOVE)
    F(563,WM_DROPFILES)
    F(564,WM_MDIREFRESHMENU)
    F(640,WM_IME_REPORT)
    F(641,WM_IME_SETCONTEXT)
    F(642,WM_IME_NOTIFY)
    F(643,WM_IME_CONTROL)
    F(644,WM_IME_COMPOSITIONFULL)
    F(645,WM_IME_SELECT)
    F(646,WM_IME_CHAR)
    F(648,WM_IME_REQUEST)
    F(656,(WM_IMEKEYDOWN,WM_IME_KEYDOWN))
    F(657,(WM_IMEKEYUP,WM_IME_KEYUP))
    F(672,WM_NCMOUSEHOVER)
    F(673,WM_MOUSEHOVER)
    F(674,WM_NCMOUSELEAVE)
    F(675,WM_MOUSELEAVE)
    F(768,WM_CUT)
    F(769,WM_COPY)
    F(770,WM_PASTE)
    F(771,WM_CLEAR)
    F(772,WM_UNDO)
    F(773,WM_RENDERFORMAT)
    F(774,WM_RENDERALLFORMATS)
    F(775,WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD)
    F(776,WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD)
    F(777,WM_PAINTCLIPBOARD)
    F(778,WM_VSCROLLCLIPBOARD)
    F(779,WM_SIZECLIPBOARD)
    F(780,WM_ASKCBFORMATNAME)
    F(781,WM_CHANGECBCHAIN)
    F(782,WM_HSCROLLCLIPBOARD)
    F(783,WM_QUERYNEWPALETTE)
    F(784,WM_PALETTEISCHANGING)
    F(785,WM_PALETTECHANGED)
    F(786,WM_HOTKEY)
    F(791,WM_PRINT)
    F(792,WM_PRINTCLIENT)
    F(793,WM_APPCOMMAND)
    F(856,WM_HANDHELDFIRST)
    F(863,WM_HANDHELDLAST)
    F(864,WM_AFXFIRST)
    F(895,WM_AFXLAST)
    F(896,WM_PENWINFIRST)
    F(897,WM_RCRESULT)
    F(898,WM_HOOKRCRESULT)
    F(899,(WM_GLOBALRCCHANGE,WM_PENMISCINFO))
    F(900,WM_SKB)
    F(901,(WM_HEDITCTL,WM_PENCTL))
    F(902,WM_PENMISC)
    F(903,WM_CTLINIT)
    F(904,WM_PENEVENT)
    F(911,WM_PENWINLAST)
    F(1024,(DDM_SETFMT,DM_GETDEFID,NIN_SELECT,TBM_GETPOS,WM_PSD_PAGESETUPDLG,WM_USER))
    F(1025,(CBEM_INSERTITEMA,DDM_DRAW,DM_SETDEFID,HKM_SETHOTKEY,PBM_SETRANGE,RB_INSERTBANDA,SB_SETTEXTA,TB_ENABLEBUTTON,TBM_GETRANGEMIN,TTM_ACTIVATE,WM_CHOOSEFONT_GETLOGFONT,WM_PSD_FULLPAGERECT))
    F(1026,(CBEM_SETIMAGELIST,DDM_CLOSE,DM_REPOSITION,HKM_GETHOTKEY,PBM_SETPOS,RB_DELETEBAND,SB_GETTEXTA,TB_CHECKBUTTON,TBM_GETRANGEMAX,WM_PSD_MINMARGINRECT))
    F(1027,(CBEM_GETIMAGELIST,DDM_BEGIN,HKM_SETRULES,PBM_DELTAPOS,RB_GETBARINFO,SB_GETTEXTLENGTHA,TBM_GETTIC,TB_PRESSBUTTON,TTM_SETDELAYTIME,WM_PSD_MARGINRECT))
    F(1028,(CBEM_GETITEMA,DDM_END,PBM_SETSTEP,RB_SETBARINFO,SB_SETPARTS,TB_HIDEBUTTON,TBM_SETTIC,TTM_ADDTOOLA,WM_PSD_GREEKTEXTRECT))
    F(1029,(CBEM_SETITEMA,PBM_STEPIT,TB_INDETERMINATE,TBM_SETPOS,TTM_DELTOOLA,WM_PSD_ENVSTAMPRECT))
    F(1030,(CBEM_GETCOMBOCONTROL,PBM_SETRANGE32,RB_SETBANDINFOA,SB_GETPARTS,TB_MARKBUTTON,TBM_SETRANGE,TTM_NEWTOOLRECTA,WM_PSD_YAFULLPAGERECT))
    F(1031,(CBEM_GETEDITCONTROL,PBM_GETRANGE,RB_SETPARENT,SB_GETBORDERS,TBM_SETRANGEMIN,TTM_RELAYEVENT))
    F(1032,(CBEM_SETEXSTYLE,PBM_GETPOS,RB_HITTEST,SB_SETMINHEIGHT,TBM_SETRANGEMAX,TTM_GETTOOLINFOA))
    F(1033,(CBEM_GETEXSTYLE,CBEM_GETEXTENDEDSTYLE,PBM_SETBARCOLOR,RB_GETRECT,SB_SIMPLE,TB_ISBUTTONENABLED,TBM_CLEARTICS,TTM_SETTOOLINFOA))
    F(1034,(CBEM_HASEDITCHANGED,RB_INSERTBANDW,SB_GETRECT,TB_ISBUTTONCHECKED,TBM_SETSEL,TTM_HITTESTA,WIZ_QUERYNUMPAGES))
    F(1035,(CBEM_INSERTITEMW,RB_SETBANDINFOW,SB_SETTEXTW,TB_ISBUTTONPRESSED,TBM_SETSELSTART,TTM_GETTEXTA,WIZ_NEXT))
    F(1036,(CBEM_SETITEMW,RB_GETBANDCOUNT,SB_GETTEXTLENGTHW,TB_ISBUTTONHIDDEN,TBM_SETSELEND,TTM_UPDATETIPTEXTA,WIZ_PREV))
    F(1037,(CBEM_GETITEMW,RB_GETROWCOUNT,SB_GETTEXTW,TB_ISBUTTONINDETERMINATE,TTM_GETTOOLCOUNT))
    F(1038,(CBEM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE,RB_GETROWHEIGHT,SB_ISSIMPLE,TB_ISBUTTONHIGHLIGHTED,TBM_GETPTICS,TTM_ENUMTOOLSA))
    F(1039,(SB_SETICON,TBM_GETTICPOS,TTM_GETCURRENTTOOLA))
    F(1040,(RB_IDTOINDEX,SB_SETTIPTEXTA,TBM_GETNUMTICS,TTM_WINDOWFROMPOINT))
    F(1041,(RB_GETTOOLTIPS,SB_SETTIPTEXTW,TBM_GETSELSTART,TB_SETSTATE,TTM_TRACKACTIVATE))
    F(1042,(RB_SETTOOLTIPS,SB_GETTIPTEXTA,TB_GETSTATE,TBM_GETSELEND,TTM_TRACKPOSITION))
    F(1043,(RB_SETBKCOLOR,SB_GETTIPTEXTW,TB_ADDBITMAP,TBM_CLEARSEL,TTM_SETTIPBKCOLOR))
    F(1044,(RB_GETBKCOLOR,SB_GETICON,TB_ADDBUTTONSA,TBM_SETTICFREQ,TTM_SETTIPTEXTCOLOR))
    F(1045,(RB_SETTEXTCOLOR,TB_INSERTBUTTONA,TBM_SETPAGESIZE,TTM_GETDELAYTIME))
    F(1046,(RB_GETTEXTCOLOR,TB_DELETEBUTTON,TBM_GETPAGESIZE,TTM_GETTIPBKCOLOR))
    F(1047,(RB_SIZETORECT,TB_GETBUTTON,TBM_SETLINESIZE,TTM_GETTIPTEXTCOLOR))
    F(1048,(RB_BEGINDRAG,TB_BUTTONCOUNT,TBM_GETLINESIZE,TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH))
    F(1049,(RB_ENDDRAG,TB_COMMANDTOINDEX,TBM_GETTHUMBRECT,TTM_GETMAXTIPWIDTH))
    F(1050,(RB_DRAGMOVE,TBM_GETCHANNELRECT,TB_SAVERESTOREA,TTM_SETMARGIN))
    F(1051,(RB_GETBARHEIGHT,TB_CUSTOMIZE,TBM_SETTHUMBLENGTH,TTM_GETMARGIN))
    F(1052,(RB_GETBANDINFOW,TB_ADDSTRINGA,TBM_GETTHUMBLENGTH,TTM_POP))
    F(1053,(RB_GETBANDINFOA,TB_GETITEMRECT,TBM_SETTOOLTIPS,TTM_UPDATE))
    F(1054,(RB_MINIMIZEBAND,TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE,TBM_GETTOOLTIPS,TTM_GETBUBBLESIZE))
    F(1055,(RB_MAXIMIZEBAND,TBM_SETTIPSIDE,TB_SETBUTTONSIZE,TTM_ADJUSTRECT))
    F(1056,(TBM_SETBUDDY,TB_SETBITMAPSIZE,TTM_SETTITLEA))
    F(1057,(MSG_FTS_JUMP_VA,TB_AUTOSIZE,TBM_GETBUDDY,TTM_SETTITLEW))
    F(1058,RB_GETBANDBORDERS)
    F(1059,(MSG_FTS_JUMP_QWORD,RB_SHOWBAND,TB_GETTOOLTIPS))
    F(1060,(MSG_REINDEX_REQUEST,TB_SETTOOLTIPS))
    F(1061,(MSG_FTS_WHERE_IS_IT,RB_SETPALETTE,TB_SETPARENT))
    F(1062,RB_GETPALETTE)
    F(1063,(RB_MOVEBAND,TB_SETROWS))
    F(1064,TB_GETROWS)
    F(1065,TB_GETBITMAPFLAGS)
    F(1066,TB_SETCMDID)
    F(1067,(RB_PUSHCHEVRON,TB_CHANGEBITMAP))
    F(1068,TB_GETBITMAP)
    F(1069,(MSG_GET_DEFFONT,TB_GETBUTTONTEXTA))
    F(1070,TB_REPLACEBITMAP)
    F(1071,TB_SETINDENT)
    F(1072,TB_SETIMAGELIST)
    F(1073,TB_GETIMAGELIST)
    F(1074,(TB_LOADIMAGES,EM_CANPASTE,TTM_ADDTOOLW))
    F(1075,(EM_DISPLAYBAND,TB_GETRECT,TTM_DELTOOLW))
    F(1076,(EM_EXGETSEL,TB_SETHOTIMAGELIST,TTM_NEWTOOLRECTW))
    F(1077,(EM_EXLIMITTEXT,TB_GETHOTIMAGELIST,TTM_GETTOOLINFOW))
    F(1078,(EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR,TB_SETDISABLEDIMAGELIST,TTM_SETTOOLINFOW))
    F(1079,(EM_EXSETSEL,TB_GETDISABLEDIMAGELIST,TTM_HITTESTW))
    F(1080,(EM_FINDTEXT,TB_SETSTYLE,TTM_GETTEXTW))
    F(1081,(EM_FORMATRANGE,TB_GETSTYLE,TTM_UPDATETIPTEXTW))
    F(1082,(EM_GETCHARFORMAT,TB_GETBUTTONSIZE,TTM_ENUMTOOLSW))
    F(1083,(EM_GETEVENTMASK,TB_SETBUTTONWIDTH,TTM_GETCURRENTTOOLW))
    F(1084,(EM_GETOLEINTERFACE,TB_SETMAXTEXTROWS))
    F(1085,(EM_GETPARAFORMAT,TB_GETTEXTROWS))
    F(1086,(EM_GETSELTEXT,TB_GETOBJECT))
    F(1087,(EM_HIDESELECTION,TB_GETBUTTONINFOW))
    F(1088,(EM_PASTESPECIAL,TB_SETBUTTONINFOW))
    F(1089,(EM_REQUESTRESIZE,TB_GETBUTTONINFOA))
    F(1090,(EM_SELECTIONTYPE,TB_SETBUTTONINFOA))
    F(1091,(EM_SETBKGNDCOLOR,TB_INSERTBUTTONW))
    F(1092,(EM_SETCHARFORMAT,TB_ADDBUTTONSW))
    F(1093,(EM_SETEVENTMASK,TB_HITTEST))
    F(1094,(EM_SETOLECALLBACK,TB_SETDRAWTEXTFLAGS))
    F(1095,(EM_SETPARAFORMAT,TB_GETHOTITEM))
    F(1096,(EM_SETTARGETDEVICE,TB_SETHOTITEM))
    F(1097,(EM_STREAMIN,TB_SETANCHORHIGHLIGHT))
    F(1098,(EM_STREAMOUT,TB_GETANCHORHIGHLIGHT))
    F(1099,(EM_GETTEXTRANGE,TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW))
    F(1100,(EM_FINDWORDBREAK,TB_SAVERESTOREW))
    F(1101,(EM_SETOPTIONS,TB_ADDSTRINGW))
    F(1102,(EM_GETOPTIONS,TB_MAPACCELERATORA))
    F(1103,(EM_FINDTEXTEX,TB_GETINSERTMARK))
    F(1104,(EM_GETWORDBREAKPROCEX,TB_SETINSERTMARK))
    F(1105,(EM_SETWORDBREAKPROCEX,TB_INSERTMARKHITTEST))
    F(1106,(EM_SETUNDOLIMIT,TB_MOVEBUTTON))
    F(1107,TB_GETMAXSIZE)
    F(1108,(EM_REDO,TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE))
    F(1109,(EM_CANREDO,TB_GETEXTENDEDSTYLE))
    F(1110,(EM_GETUNDONAME,TB_GETPADDING))
    F(1111,(EM_GETREDONAME,TB_SETPADDING))
    F(1112,(EM_STOPGROUPTYPING,TB_SETINSERTMARKCOLOR))
    F(1113,(EM_SETTEXTMODE,TB_GETINSERTMARKCOLOR))
    F(1114,(EM_GETTEXTMODE,TB_MAPACCELERATORW))
    F(1115,(EM_AUTOURLDETECT,TB_GETSTRINGW))
    F(1116,(EM_GETAUTOURLDETECT,TB_GETSTRINGA))
    F(1117,EM_SETPALETTE)
    F(1118,EM_GETTEXTEX)
    F(1119,EM_GETTEXTLENGTHEX)
    F(1120,EM_SHOWSCROLLBAR)
    F(1121,EM_SETTEXTEX)
    F(1123,TAPI_REPLY)
    F(1124,(ACM_OPENA,BFFM_SETSTATUSTEXTA,CDM_GETSPEC,EM_SETPUNCTUATION,IPM_CLEARADDRESS,WM_CAP_UNICODE_START))
    F(1125,(ACM_PLAY,BFFM_ENABLEOK,CDM_GETFILEPATH,EM_GETPUNCTUATION,IPM_SETADDRESS,PSM_SETCURSEL,UDM_SETRANGE,WM_CHOOSEFONT_SETLOGFONT))
    F(1126,(ACM_STOP,BFFM_SETSELECTIONA,CDM_GETFOLDERPATH,EM_SETWORDWRAPMODE,IPM_GETADDRESS,PSM_REMOVEPAGE,UDM_GETRANGE,WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_ERRORW,WM_CHOOSEFONT_SETFLAGS))
    F(1127,(ACM_OPENW,BFFM_SETSELECTIONW,CDM_GETFOLDERIDLIST,EM_GETWORDWRAPMODE,IPM_SETRANGE,PSM_ADDPAGE,UDM_SETPOS,WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_STATUSW))
    F(1128,(BFFM_SETSTATUSTEXTW,CDM_SETCONTROLTEXT,EM_SETIMECOLOR,IPM_SETFOCUS,PSM_CHANGED,UDM_GETPOS))
    F(1129,(CDM_HIDECONTROL,EM_GETIMECOLOR,IPM_ISBLANK,PSM_RESTARTWINDOWS,UDM_SETBUDDY))
    F(1130,(CDM_SETDEFEXT,EM_SETIMEOPTIONS,PSM_REBOOTSYSTEM,UDM_GETBUDDY))
    F(1131,(EM_GETIMEOPTIONS,PSM_CANCELTOCLOSE,UDM_SETACCEL))
    F(1132,(EM_CONVPOSITION,EM_CONVPOSITION,PSM_QUERYSIBLINGS,UDM_GETACCEL))
    F(1133,(MCIWNDM_GETZOOM,PSM_UNCHANGED,UDM_SETBASE))
    F(1134,(PSM_APPLY,UDM_GETBASE))
    F(1135,(PSM_SETTITLEA,UDM_SETRANGE32))
    F(1136,(PSM_SETWIZBUTTONS,UDM_GETRANGE32,WM_CAP_DRIVER_GET_NAMEW))
    F(1137,(PSM_PRESSBUTTON,UDM_SETPOS32,WM_CAP_DRIVER_GET_VERSIONW))
    F(1138,(PSM_SETCURSELID,UDM_GETPOS32))
    F(1139,PSM_SETFINISHTEXTA)
    F(1140,PSM_GETTABCONTROL)
    F(1141,PSM_ISDIALOGMESSAGE)
    F(1142,(MCIWNDM_REALIZE,PSM_GETCURRENTPAGEHWND))
    F(1143,(MCIWNDM_SETTIMEFORMATA,PSM_INSERTPAGE))
    F(1144,(EM_SETLANGOPTIONS,MCIWNDM_GETTIMEFORMATA,PSM_SETTITLEW,WM_CAP_FILE_SET_CAPTURE_FILEW))
    F(1145,(EM_GETLANGOPTIONS,MCIWNDM_VALIDATEMEDIA,PSM_SETFINISHTEXTW,WM_CAP_FILE_GET_CAPTURE_FILEW))
    F(1146,EM_GETIMECOMPMODE)
    F(1147,(EM_FINDTEXTW,MCIWNDM_PLAYTO,WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEASW))
    F(1148,(EM_FINDTEXTEXW,MCIWNDM_GETFILENAMEA))
    F(1149,(EM_RECONVERSION,MCIWNDM_GETDEVICEA,PSM_SETHEADERTITLEA,WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIBW))
    F(1150,(EM_SETIMEMODEBIAS,MCIWNDM_GETPALETTE,PSM_SETHEADERTITLEW))
    F(1151,(EM_GETIMEMODEBIAS,MCIWNDM_SETPALETTE,PSM_SETHEADERSUBTITLEA))
    F(1152,(MCIWNDM_GETERRORA,PSM_SETHEADERSUBTITLEW))
    F(1153,PSM_HWNDTOINDEX)
    F(1154,PSM_INDEXTOHWND)
    F(1155,(MCIWNDM_SETINACTIVETIMER,PSM_PAGETOINDEX))
    F(1156,PSM_INDEXTOPAGE)
    F(1157,(DL_BEGINDRAG,MCIWNDM_GETINACTIVETIMER,PSM_IDTOINDEX))
    F(1158,(DL_DRAGGING,PSM_INDEXTOID))
    F(1159,(DL_DROPPED,PSM_GETRESULT))
    F(1160,(DL_CANCELDRAG,PSM_RECALCPAGESIZES))
    F(1164,MCIWNDM_GET_SOURCE)
    F(1165,MCIWNDM_PUT_SOURCE)
    F(1166,MCIWNDM_GET_DEST)
    F(1167,MCIWNDM_PUT_DEST)
    F(1168,MCIWNDM_CAN_PLAY)
    F(1169,MCIWNDM_CAN_WINDOW)
    F(1170,MCIWNDM_CAN_RECORD)
    F(1171,MCIWNDM_CAN_SAVE)
    F(1172,MCIWNDM_CAN_EJECT)
    F(1173,MCIWNDM_CAN_CONFIG)
    F(1174,(IE_GETINK,MCIWNDM_PALETTEKICK))
    F(1175,IE_SETINK)
    F(1176,IE_GETPENTIP)
    F(1177,IE_SETPENTIP)
    F(1178,IE_GETERASERTIP)
    F(1179,IE_SETERASERTIP)
    F(1180,IE_GETBKGND)
    F(1181,IE_SETBKGND)
    F(1182,IE_GETGRIDORIGIN)
    F(1183,IE_SETGRIDORIGIN)
    F(1184,IE_GETGRIDPEN)
    F(1185,IE_SETGRIDPEN)
    F(1186,IE_GETGRIDSIZE)
    F(1187,IE_SETGRIDSIZE)
    F(1188,IE_GETMODE)
    F(1189,IE_SETMODE)
    F(1190,(IE_GETINKRECT,WM_CAP_SET_MCI_DEVICEW))
    F(1191,WM_CAP_GET_MCI_DEVICEW)
    F(1204,WM_CAP_PAL_OPENW)
    F(1205,WM_CAP_PAL_SAVEW)
    F(1208,IE_GETAPPDATA)
    F(1209,IE_SETAPPDATA)
    F(1210,IE_GETDRAWOPTS)
    F(1211,IE_SETDRAWOPTS)
    F(1212,IE_GETFORMAT)
    F(1213,IE_SETFORMAT)
    F(1214,IE_GETINKINPUT)
    F(1215,IE_SETINKINPUT)
    F(1216,IE_GETNOTIFY)
    F(1217,IE_SETNOTIFY)
    F(1218,IE_GETRECOG)
    F(1219,IE_SETRECOG)
    F(1220,IE_GETSECURITY)
    F(1221,IE_SETSECURITY)
    F(1222,IE_GETSEL)
    F(1223,IE_SETSEL)
    F(1224,(EM_SETBIDIOPTIONS,IE_DOCOMMAND,MCIWNDM_NOTIFYMODE))
    F(1225,(EM_GETBIDIOPTIONS,IE_GETCOMMAND))
    F(1226,(EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS,IE_GETCOUNT))
    F(1227,(EM_GETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS,IE_GETGESTURE,MCIWNDM_NOTIFYMEDIA))
    F(1228,(EM_SETEDITSTYLE,IE_GETMENU))
    F(1229,(EM_GETEDITSTYLE,IE_GETPAINTDC,MCIWNDM_NOTIFYERROR))
    F(1230,IE_GETPDEVENT)
    F(1231,IE_GETSELCOUNT)
    F(1232,IE_GETSELITEMS)
    F(1233,IE_GETSTYLE)
    F(1243,MCIWNDM_SETTIMEFORMATW)
    F(1244,(EM_OUTLINE,MCIWNDM_GETTIMEFORMATW))
    F(1245,EM_GETSCROLLPOS)
    F(1246,(EM_SETSCROLLPOS,EM_SETSCROLLPOS))
    F(1247,EM_SETFONTSIZE)
    F(1248,(EM_GETZOOM,MCIWNDM_GETFILENAMEW))
    F(1249,(EM_SETZOOM,MCIWNDM_GETDEVICEW))
    F(1250,EM_GETVIEWKIND)
    F(1251,EM_SETVIEWKIND)
    F(1252,(EM_GETPAGE,MCIWNDM_GETERRORW))
    F(1253,EM_SETPAGE)
    F(1254,EM_GETHYPHENATEINFO)
    F(1255,EM_SETHYPHENATEINFO)
    F(1259,EM_GETPAGEROTATE)
    F(1260,EM_SETPAGEROTATE)
    F(1261,EM_GETCTFMODEBIAS)
    F(1262,EM_SETCTFMODEBIAS)
    F(1264,EM_GETCTFOPENSTATUS)
    F(1265,EM_SETCTFOPENSTATUS)
    F(1266,EM_GETIMECOMPTEXT)
    F(1267,EM_ISIME)
    F(1268,EM_GETIMEPROPERTY)
    F(1293,EM_GETQUERYRTFOBJ)
    F(1294,EM_SETQUERYRTFOBJ)
    F(1536,FM_GETFOCUS)
    F(1537,FM_GETDRIVEINFOA)
    F(1538,FM_GETSELCOUNT)
    F(1539,FM_GETSELCOUNTLFN)
    F(1540,FM_GETFILESELA)
    F(1541,FM_GETFILESELLFNA)
    F(1542,FM_REFRESH_WINDOWS)
    F(1543,FM_RELOAD_EXTENSIONS)
    F(1553,FM_GETDRIVEINFOW)
    F(1556,FM_GETFILESELW)
    F(1557,FM_GETFILESELLFNW)
    F(1625,WLX_WM_SAS)
    F(2024,(SM_GETSELCOUNT,UM_GETSELCOUNT,WM_CPL_LAUNCH))
    F(2025,(SM_GETSERVERSELA,UM_GETUSERSELA,WM_CPL_LAUNCHED))
    F(2026,(SM_GETSERVERSELW,UM_GETUSERSELW))
    F(2027,(SM_GETCURFOCUSA,UM_GETGROUPSELA))
    F(2028,(SM_GETCURFOCUSW,UM_GETGROUPSELW))
    F(2029,(SM_GETOPTIONS,UM_GETCURFOCUSA))
    F(2030,UM_GETCURFOCUSW)
    F(2031,UM_GETOPTIONS)
    F(2032,UM_GETOPTIONS2)
    F(4096,LVM_GETBKCOLOR)
    F(4097,LVM_SETBKCOLOR)
    F(4098,LVM_GETIMAGELIST)
    F(4099,LVM_SETIMAGELIST)
    F(4100,LVM_GETITEMCOUNT)
    F(4101,LVM_GETITEMA)
    F(4102,LVM_SETITEMA)
    F(4103,LVM_INSERTITEMA)
    F(4104,LVM_DELETEITEM)
    F(4105,LVM_DELETEALLITEMS)
    F(4106,LVM_GETCALLBACKMASK)
    F(4107,LVM_SETCALLBACKMASK)
    F(4108,LVM_GETNEXTITEM)
    F(4109,LVM_FINDITEMA)
    F(4110,LVM_GETITEMRECT)
    F(4111,LVM_SETITEMPOSITION)
    F(4112,LVM_GETITEMPOSITION)
    F(4113,LVM_GETSTRINGWIDTHA)
    F(4114,LVM_HITTEST)
    F(4115,LVM_ENSUREVISIBLE)
    F(4116,LVM_SCROLL)
    F(4117,LVM_REDRAWITEMS)
    F(4118,LVM_ARRANGE)
    F(4119,LVM_EDITLABELA)
    F(4120,LVM_GETEDITCONTROL)
    F(4121,LVM_GETCOLUMNA)
    F(4122,LVM_SETCOLUMNA)
    F(4123,LVM_INSERTCOLUMNA)
    F(4124,LVM_DELETECOLUMN)
    F(4125,LVM_GETCOLUMNWIDTH)
    F(4126,LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH)
    F(4127,LVM_GETHEADER)
    F(4129,LVM_CREATEDRAGIMAGE)
    F(4130,LVM_GETVIEWRECT)
    F(4131,LVM_GETTEXTCOLOR)
    F(4132,LVM_SETTEXTCOLOR)
    F(4133,LVM_GETTEXTBKCOLOR)
    F(4134,LVM_SETTEXTBKCOLOR)
    F(4135,LVM_GETTOPINDEX)
    F(4136,LVM_GETCOUNTPERPAGE)
    F(4137,LVM_GETORIGIN)
    F(4138,LVM_UPDATE)
    F(4139,LVM_SETITEMSTATE)
    F(4140,LVM_GETITEMSTATE)
    F(4141,LVM_GETITEMTEXTA)
    F(4142,LVM_SETITEMTEXTA)
    F(4143,LVM_SETITEMCOUNT)
    F(4144,LVM_SORTITEMS)
    F(4145,LVM_SETITEMPOSITION32)
    F(4146,LVM_GETSELECTEDCOUNT)
    F(4147,LVM_GETITEMSPACING)
    F(4148,LVM_GETISEARCHSTRINGA)
    F(4149,LVM_SETICONSPACING)
    F(4150,LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE)
    F(4151,LVM_GETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE)
    F(4152,LVM_GETSUBITEMRECT)
    F(4153,LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST)
    F(4154,LVM_SETCOLUMNORDERARRAY)
    F(4155,LVM_GETCOLUMNORDERARRAY)
    F(4156,LVM_SETHOTITEM)
    F(4157,LVM_GETHOTITEM)
    F(4158,LVM_SETHOTCURSOR)
    F(4159,LVM_GETHOTCURSOR)
    F(4160,LVM_APPROXIMATEVIEWRECT)
    F(4161,LVM_SETWORKAREAS)
    F(4162,LVM_GETSELECTIONMARK)
    F(4163,LVM_SETSELECTIONMARK)
    F(4164,LVM_SETBKIMAGEA)
    F(4165,LVM_GETBKIMAGEA)
    F(4166,LVM_GETWORKAREAS)
    F(4167,LVM_SETHOVERTIME)
    F(4168,LVM_GETHOVERTIME)
    F(4169,LVM_GETNUMBEROFWORKAREAS)
    F(4170,LVM_SETTOOLTIPS)
    F(4171,LVM_GETITEMW)
    F(4172,LVM_SETITEMW)
    F(4173,LVM_INSERTITEMW)
    F(4174,LVM_GETTOOLTIPS)
    F(4179,LVM_FINDITEMW)
    F(4183,LVM_GETSTRINGWIDTHW)
    F(4191,LVM_GETCOLUMNW)
    F(4192,LVM_SETCOLUMNW)
    F(4193,LVM_INSERTCOLUMNW)
    F(4211,LVM_GETITEMTEXTW)
    F(4212,LVM_SETITEMTEXTW)
    F(4213,LVM_GETISEARCHSTRINGW)
    F(4214,LVM_EDITLABELW)
    F(4235,LVM_GETBKIMAGEW)
    F(4236,LVM_SETSELECTEDCOLUMN)
    F(4237,LVM_SETTILEWIDTH)
    F(4238,LVM_SETVIEW)
    F(4239,LVM_GETVIEW)
    F(4241,LVM_INSERTGROUP)
    F(4243,LVM_SETGROUPINFO)
    F(4245,LVM_GETGROUPINFO)
    F(4246,LVM_REMOVEGROUP)
    F(4247,LVM_MOVEGROUP)
    F(4250,LVM_MOVEITEMTOGROUP)
    F(4251,LVM_SETGROUPMETRICS)
    F(4252,LVM_GETGROUPMETRICS)
    F(4253,LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW)
    F(4254,LVM_SORTGROUPS)
    F(4255,LVM_INSERTGROUPSORTED)
    F(4256,LVM_REMOVEALLGROUPS)
    F(4257,LVM_HASGROUP)
    F(4258,LVM_SETTILEVIEWINFO)
    F(4259,LVM_GETTILEVIEWINFO)
    F(4260,LVM_SETTILEINFO)
    F(4261,LVM_GETTILEINFO)
    F(4262,LVM_SETINSERTMARK)
    F(4263,LVM_GETINSERTMARK)
    F(4264,LVM_INSERTMARKHITTEST)
    F(4265,LVM_GETINSERTMARKRECT)
    F(4266,LVM_SETINSERTMARKCOLOR)
    F(4267,LVM_GETINSERTMARKCOLOR)
    F(4269,LVM_SETINFOTIP)
    F(4270,LVM_GETSELECTEDCOLUMN)
    F(4271,LVM_ISGROUPVIEWENABLED)
    F(4272,LVM_GETOUTLINECOLOR)
    F(4273,LVM_SETOUTLINECOLOR)
    F(4275,LVM_CANCELEDITLABEL)
    F(4276,LVM_MAPINDEXTOID)
    F(4277,LVM_MAPIDTOINDEX)
    F(4278,LVM_ISITEMVISIBLE)
    F(8192,OCM__BASE)
    F(8197,LVM_SETUNICODEFORMAT)
    F(8198,LVM_GETUNICODEFORMAT)
    F(8217,OCM_CTLCOLOR)
    F(8235,OCM_DRAWITEM)
    F(8236,OCM_MEASUREITEM)
    F(8237,OCM_DELETEITEM)
    F(8238,OCM_VKEYTOITEM)
    F(8239,OCM_CHARTOITEM)
    F(8249,OCM_COMPAREITEM)
    F(8270,OCM_NOTIFY)
    F(8465,OCM_COMMAND)
    F(8468,OCM_HSCROLL)
    F(8469,OCM_VSCROLL)
    F(8498,OCM_CTLCOLORMSGBOX)
    F(8499,OCM_CTLCOLOREDIT)
    F(8500,OCM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX)
    F(8501,OCM_CTLCOLORBTN)
    F(8502,OCM_CTLCOLORDLG)
    F(8503,OCM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR)
    F(8504,OCM_CTLCOLORSTATIC)
    F(8720,OCM_PARENTNOTIFY)
    F(32768,WM_APP)
    F(52429,WM_RASDIALEVENT)
  }
  #undef F
  return 0;
}

std::string id2str(int id){
  auto*p=id2str_impl(id);
  return p?p:"unk("+std::to_string(id)+")";
}

int main(){
  std::cout << "id2str(512) == " << id2str(512) << std::endl;
}
```

diff (compared to https://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages):
https://www.diffchecker.com/VvLzYadB